# python dataframe cal std

Tags: python, dataframe

I build dataframe as following:

```
date= ['19910603', '19910604']
v1 = [37.7, 37.6]
v2 = [36.3, 36.5]
pd1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':date, '600123.SH': v1, '600789.SH': v2})
pd1.set_index("date", inplace=True)

v11 = [37.3, 37.3]
v21 = [36.2, 36.1]

pd2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':date, '600123.SH': v11, '600789.SH': v21})
pd2.set_index("date", inplace=True)

v12= [36.3, 36.3]
v22 = [35.2, 35.1]

pd3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':date, '600123.SH': v12, '600789.SH': v22})
pd3.set_index("date", inplace=True)

columns=[('close','600123.SH'),('close','600789.SH')]
pd1.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)

columns=[('open','600123.SH'),('open','600789.SH')]
pd2.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)

columns=[('high','600123.SH'),('high','600789.SH')]
pd3.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)

pff =  pd.merge(pd1, pd2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
pff =  pd.merge(pff, pd3, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)

print pff
```

This dataframe has two level column, I want to use the numpy.std to calculate the std for each date and each security with given values of close, open and high. I have no ideas on how to do these kind of calculation on data frame.
Please help and much thanks.

Comment: I want to calculate the the standard deviation for the two securities (600123.SH,600789.SH ) for the two dates(19910603,19910604). For the security 600123.SH for the date 19910603, I want to get the std as numpy.std([37.7, 37.3, 36.3]). The the calculation should be put in a new column in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape + [`std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html):

```
print (pff.stack())
                    close  high  open
date                                 
19910603 600123.SH   37.7  36.3  37.3
         600789.SH   36.3  35.2  36.2
19910604 600123.SH   37.6  36.3  37.3
         600789.SH   36.5  35.1  36.1

print (pff.stack().std(axis=1))
date               
19910603  600123.SH    0.721110
          600789.SH    0.608276
19910604  600123.SH    0.680686
          600789.SH    0.721110
dtype: float64
```

[`numpy.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) is same as `pandas std`, only is necessary change `ddof` to `0`, because default is `1`.

```
print (np.std(pff.stack(), axis=1))
date               
19910603  600123.SH    0.588784
          600789.SH    0.496655
19910604  600123.SH    0.555778
          600789.SH    0.588784
dtype: float64
```

is same as:

```
print (pff.stack().std(ddof=0, axis=1))
date               
19910603  600123.SH    0.588784
          600789.SH    0.496655
19910604  600123.SH    0.555778
          600789.SH    0.588784
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This solved my problems: pff.stack().std(ddof=0, axis=1).unstack() could get teh final result. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to calculate the standard deviations of each asset's history of close, open and high prices. Pandas DataFrames and Series have many common NumPy functions integrated in them as methods, including `.std()`:

```
pff.std()
```